Migrating Azure Devops Server 2020 databases to a new dev server Reporting Server error
I have taken a copy of all my Production Azure Devops databases and restored then to a different server for a DEV environment. All has gone well, I used the clone option when running the installation wizard.
However, I am now trying to configure the Report Services in the DEV Azure Devops server.
I have successfully done the Anaylysis and  Warehouse section.
When it comes to the Reports section, I successfully get the server and the WebService and Report manager URL, have the correct account for accessing the datasources
When I click the Ok button I receive the following Error "The user or group name 'username' is not recognized"
This is an old user who initially setup the production environment. He has left the company.
Does anyone know where this user is being access from and how I can change it?
Thanks in advance
Looked in the databases and cannot find the user name

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
